# Laravel search & filter

Tags: php, laravel

This will display the current url page and I want to filter the contents from the table of view page... any idea how to do it in controller?

Here students is current view page

Where did I make a mistake? My table's fields are name, country, age.

```html
<form method='get' style="display:inline-block;width: 260px;" action='{{Request::url()}}'>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="q" value="{{ Request::get('q') }}" class="form-control input-sm pull-{{ trans('crudbooster.right') }}" placeholder="{{trans('crudbooster.filter_search')}}"/>
        {!! CRUDBooster::getUrlParameters(['q']) !!}
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            @if(Request::get('q'))
                <?php 
                    $parameters = Request::all();
                    unset($parameters['q']);
                    $build_query = urldecode(http_build_query($parameters));
                    $build_query = ($build_query)?"?".$build_query:"";
                    $build_query = (Request::all())?$build_query:"";
                ?>
                <button type='button' onclick='location.href="{{ CRUDBooster::mainpath().$build_query}}"' title="{{trans('crudbooster.button_reset')}}" class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'><i class='fa fa-ban'></i></button>
            @endif
            <button type='submit' class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

this is my controller code.

```html
public function getstudents(Request $request)
{


$students =DB::table('users')
->orderBy('created_at',desc)
->get();
 

$searchby =$request->get('q');

 $students = DB::table('students')
       ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $searchby . '%')
                  ->get();
return view('students',compact('students'));

}
```

Comment: it searches nothing only runs the reset code...

Comment: what from the students table do you want to display?